# Applying button for each step, or delaying javascript recursion

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, delay, towers-of-hanoi

I have made a small program using javascript to solve the Tower of Hanoi problem. I used 3 towers of DIVs and gave the first tower a black color, and for the rest i gave white. When I want the program to swap 2 elements, it basically swaps the properties of the proper DIVs. The code works perfectly, but I want each step to be visible and at the current state it is only a flash from the start to the end. I have tried using a button for each step and it didnt work and so the setTimeout(). (Sorry for my bad England :c )

```
var from = 1;
var to = 2;
var help = 3;

function swap(from, to){
    while (...){
        if (...){
            while(...){
                if (...){
                    //swaps the properties of the divs
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


function hanoi(n, from, to, help){
    if (n == 1){
        swap(from, to);
    }
    else{
        hanoi(n-1, from, help, to);
        swap(from, to);
        hanoi(n-1, help, to, from);
    }
}
```

I have tried this, but this just delayed the flash by 2 seconds:

```
function hanoi(n, from, to, help){
    if (n == 1){
        setTimeout(function(){swap(from, to);}, 2000);
    }
    else{
        hanoi(n-1, from, help, to);
        setTimeout(function(){swap(from, to);}, 2000);
        hanoi(n-1, help, to, from);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a generator instead of a regular function.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest checking out how setTimeout works with the JavaScript event stack. [Here's an awesome video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&vl=en).

Here's your process.

1. You call `hanoi` which, if it passes through the if check, automatically calls itself again.
2. Because the setTimeout sends the execution of that code to the webapis to be executed later, it automatically fires the second `hanoi` in that block.
3. This keeps running firing more `hanoi`s and creating more setTimeouts which send the execution of `swap` to the webapis.
4. Because all of your setTimeouts are being fired at "the same time", they resolve their 2 second wait at the same time.

[Jonas Wilms's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53506246/10559113) explains how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

In your last code block, the recursive function executes recursively, creates all the timeouts, and after 2 seconds all the timeouts call back shortly after another, thats why it is flashing ([in depth explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53506394/5260024)).    Instead you want to also delay the recursive call:

```
 function hanoi(n, from, to, help){
   if (n == 1){
    setTimeout(function(){swap(from, to);}, 2000);
   } else{
    setTimeout(function() {
       hanoi(n-1, from, help, to);
       swap(from, to);
       hanoi(n-1, help, to, from);
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

---

However while that works, this code is not really beautiful. It is not really the job of the Hanoi method to visualize & delay the loop. Instead I would write the hanoi logic in a method that can be interrupted, and then this can be called by a handler function that rerenders and delays. That is a perfect usecase for generators:

```
 function* hanoi(n, from, to, help){
    if (n == 1){
     swap(from, to);
    } else{
       yield* hanoi(n-1, from, help, to);
       swap(from, to);
       yield* hanoi(n-1, help, to, from);
   }
   yield; // Pass execution back to the "runStepByStep" loop, rerendering & delaying happens here
}
```

And the handler is:

```
 const timer = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

 async function runStepByStep(iterator) {
   let done = false;
  do {
    ({ done } = iterator.next());
    rerender(); // TODO: Implement this
    await timer(2000);
  } while(!done);
}

 runStepByStep( hanoi(10, 0, 2, 1) );
```